# InstallError in Ruby on rails 3

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting the following error when i was trying to make one new app using Rails 3 and mysql.

I typed "rails new myapp -d mysql" and pressed on enter but the it displayed the below error.

Error:

```
Gem::InstallError: execjs requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0.
An error occurred while installing execjs (2.5.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install execjs -v '2.5.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Please help me to resolve this error and make a new project with mysql successfully.I am using rails version 3.2.19 and ruby 1.9.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Gem::InstallError: execjs requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0.
```

This line in error suggests you need ruby version 2.0 or greater

> Follow https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/ to get latest ruby

Comment: Hi Akash,I am currently using ruby-1.9.3.Is there any problem If i will ignore this gem.

Comment: try changing execjs version to 1.3.0 which uses ruby 1.9

Comment: Ruby 2.0 isn't an option for me -- I'm developing on MS Windows (no choice) and too much Ruby 2.0 stuff hasn't been ported to Windows yet.